# Android with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv for android on my image processing application. I configured opencv library and it works well with the sample projects. When I try to run my own project using opencv, I get "Android Library Projects cannot be Launched". I have checked the Project properties ,is Library is checked for my project for the openCV library,Cleaning the project does not help either.
Please help me.

Comment: What IDE are you running this in? Are you running against an emulator or a phone? Which phone? Which Android version?

Comment: `isLibrary` shouldn't be checked if you're writing an app that isn't a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to configure OpenCV4Android library for your projects:

1. Import the OpenCV library project to your workspace.
2. Go to OpenCV library project->Properties->Android.
3. Mark the "isLibrary" checked if it is not.
4. Go to YourProject->Properties->Android. In Library Section click on add. select OpenCV Library from the list.
5. Do your necessary codes in your project and compile it.

If you need more details, You can get from [here.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) Remember, your project should not be marked as library project. So don't mark the isLibrary checked in your project properties.

Thanks.